# Calculate length of multiple lists within a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to calculate the length of each element of a list within a data.table. Here is a small example.

```
test<-data.table(
  x = list(c(1,2,3),c(1)),
  y = list(c(2,3),c(1,2,3))
)

#This works:
test[,length_x:=sapply(x,length)]
test[,length_y:=sapply(y,length)]

#But this does not, can somebody explain why and how to correct it:
test[,c("length_x","length_y"):=sapply(.SD,length)]
```

Can somebody explain why the second part of the code does not work and how to correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te issue here is that you actually need two levels of iteration

- Iteration over the columns with `lapply(.SD, ...)`
- Iteration over the column elements to evaluate a "cellwise" length

```r
test[, c("length_x", "length_y") := lapply(.SD, function(column) {
  sapply(column, length)
})]
```

This can be simplified further using the ellipses (`...`) in `lapply`.

```r
test[, c("length_x", "length_y") := lapply(.SD, sapply, length)]
```

Comment: Good answer, upvoted!. I guess you can try `lengths`, which can shorten your code.

Answer (score 4):

Try `lengths` within `data.table` like below

```
> test[, paste0("length_", names(test)) := Map(lengths, .SD)][]
       x     y length_x length_y
1: 1,2,3   2,3        3        2
2:     1 1,2,3        1        3
```